# "Non-exhaustive patterns in function" error when appending value before function call

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns, guard-clause

I'm not sure what I'm not handling. Suppose I have a function, that converts an integer to a string. Call it `converter`.

Now, to convert position integer to string, I just call `converter`. To convert a negative integer to string, I append `-` to the `converter` call.

This is my code:

```
converter :: Integer -> String
converter x
    | x == 0 = "0"
    | x == 1 = "1"
    | x == 2 = "2"
    | x == 3 = "3"
    | x == 4 = "4"
    | x == 5 = "5"
    | x == 6 = "6"
    | x == 7 = "7"
    | x == 8 = "8"
    | x == 9 = "9"
    | x > 9 = z
    where
    (a, b) = divMod x 10
    z = (converter a) ++ (converter b)

negOrPosConverter :: NegOrPosInteger -> String
negOrPosConverter (ActualInt x)
    | x >= 0 = converter x
    | x < 0 = "-" ++ (converter x)
```

When I run the code and try `negOrPosConverter (ActualInt (-200))` I get this error:

```
"-*** Exception: theConverter.hs:(19,1)-(27,32): Non-exhaustive patterns in function converter
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Side note: you can replace the main body of `converter` with `if ((0<=x) && (x<10)) then show x else z`. `show` is a useful function from the main library which can convert most non-string values into strings.

Comment: Remember to turn on warnings, so to discover these issues at compile time. If you have a list of guards `| condition = something | condition2 = something | ...` the last one should be `... | otherwise = something` to be sure of catching all the remaining cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `converter` is only defined for nonnegative numbers. You prepend a `"-"` when it's negative, but you forgot to invert the actual number you pass to it. Try this instead:

```
negOrPosConverter :: NegOrPosInteger -> String
negOrPosConverter (ActualInt x)
    | x >= 0 = converter x
    | x < 0 = '-' : converter (-x)
```

Note `converter (-x)` instead of `converter x`.

---

Also, if this isn't just for practice, note that the `show` function already exists in Prelude to convert numbers (and lots of other things too) into strings.

Comment: Works. Just to clarify, when I do `"-" ++ (converter x)`, what exactly is it passing to `converter` then to make my code fail? I thought putting it in brackets `(converter x)` would just pass `x` to converter, and then add the `-`? Yup. Just to learn and get used to Haskell programming.

Comment: @user2719875 It does just pass `x` to converter. The problem is that `x` is negative in that case, and `converter` doesn't work on negative numbers.

Comment: Ohhhhh. Got it. So what exactly does `x < 0 = '-' : converter (-x)` do? I haven't learned syntax of `:` yet. I'm guessing it remove the `-` temporarily? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2719875 `'-' :` does the exact same thing as `"-" ++`. `:` just lets you add one element at a time more efficiently than `++`.

Comment: Ok, so `converter (-x)` is basically what solves the problem, right? The line `x < 0 = '-' : converter (-x)` says, if `x < 0` i.e. a negative integer, then pass it as an argument to `converter` After negating it (`converter (-x)`), to make it positive when passing it to `converter`. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @user2719875 Yes.

Comment: @user2719875  If you look at the definition of `(++)`, you'll find the relevant case to be `(x:xs) ++ ys = x : xs ++ ys`, and `"-"` is the same thing as `'-':[]`, so `"-" ++ converter x` is equivalent to `'-' : converter x`, which prepends a `'-'` to the result of `converter x`.